# Regex Dynamic Find and Replace

Tags: php, regex, replace

I am trying to execute a find/replace function using regex in PHP. I have successfully found all instances of `isset($ServerVars->varGet("XXXX"))` using the following regex:

```
\(isset\(\$ServerVars->varGet(.*?\)\))
```

However, I now need to replace the string with this:

```
NULL !== $ServerVars->varGet("XXXX")
```

How can I replace all instances of `isset($ServerVars->varGet("XXXX"))` with `NULL !== $ServerVars->varGet("XXXX")`?

Note that in the above example, `"XXXX"` is simply a placeholder; this value will vary.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: Try `preg_replace('~isset\((\$ServerVars->varGet\("[^"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^"\\\\]*)*"\))\)~s', 'NULL !== $1', $text)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a capture group `()` around the variable data `.*?` and use the back-reference to that first group `$1` in the replacement:

```
$string = preg_replace('/isset\(\$ServerVars->varGet\((.*?)\)\)/',
                       'NULL !== $ServerVars->varGet($1)', $string);
```

But maybe you want `!empty($ServerVars->varGet("XXXX"))`?  Not sure what it's returning or what you're doing.

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/f320D)